# CSS problems, left menu pushes content down

Tags: css

I am having some problems with my design, my left menu keeps pushing the content down, they are ment to be side by side! I have tryed everything, it just won't work :(

I have uploaded it to a temp location
http://cosplay.dk/New/Cosplay%20Denmark%20-%20Index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#wrapper {overflow:hidden;}
#left-menu, #content {float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float `#left-menu` and `#content` left. Specify a width as well.

Comment: No you don't. At least not in the uploaded source. It appears some of your css files are pointing to localhost - upload them and change the url to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `float:left;`, then when you need to go to a new line, use `clear:both;`

Comment: 2 more characers :D minimum limit on the comment